# Python: how to search and count the occurances of a root word in a string in a file?

Tags: python

Let's assume we want to count the frequency of the word "hope" in a file. But our lines contain other words such as "hopefully", "hopeful" or "hopeless".

I was able to write a small code that open a file and search for specific word such as "hopelessly" and count it's occurances.

```
def read_file():
    Lines = "empty.txt"
    fileName = "feedbacks.txt"
    if fileName != None:
        mode = "r"
        try:
            Lines  = open(fileName,mode)
        except IOError as e:
            e = "file can't be open"
    return Lines

def freq(Lines, str):
    words = Lines.split()
    words_list = []
    for i in words:
        if i == str:
            words_list.append(word)
    print(len(words_list))

Lines = read_file().read()

freq(Lines, "hopelessly") # output is 3
freq(Lines, "hopeless") # output is 4
freq(Lines, "hopeful") # output is 2
```

But how can I search all the words that contains the root word, e.g.: "hope" ?

P.S.: I am a total newbie to Python

Comment: You need to use methods from natural language processing. Specifically you should read about stemming and lemmatization: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/stemming-lemmatization-python

Comment: Do you expect the lemma `hope` to find `hoping` as well?

Comment: @usr2564301 : that would be an ultimate goal. But I guess I need some sort of dictioanry to work out all the root and leaves of the wrod (whether it is a verb or an adjuctive, whether it has a suffix or prefix and whether it is present past or else) .

Comment: @ReutSharabani : Thank you a lot .. I am will definitly give it a visit and try to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def freq(Lines, str):
    words = Lines.split()
    words_list = []
    for i in words:
        if str in i:
            words_list.append(word)
    print(len(words_list))
```

then call:

```
freq(Lines, "hope")
```

if you want to check if your word starts with a string you can use:

```
if i.startswith(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what root word you are looking for, you can check for `in` instead of equality:

```
def freq(Lines, str):
    words = Lines.split()
    words_list = []
    for i in words:
        if i in str: # this is changed
            words_list.append(word)
    print(len(words_list))
```

Comment: Not true; `in` also works for 'inside', not only 'at the start'. This will match, for example, the `hope` in `orthopedic`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = """hopelessly") # output is 3
freq(Lines, "hopeless") # output is 4
freq(Lines, "hopeful"""

matches = re.findall(r"hope[a-z]*",text)
print(matches)
```

This code produces output ['hopelessly', 'hopeless', 'hopeful']

len(matches) -> Returns the count

Replace text with your payload and for simple usages or unchanged word roots should do the trick.

Comment: This is a very neat and fast solution. But I wanted to learn how to do it manualy without importing a module. Thanks